# Is it possible to declare parameters optional for an action in the ABI?

Tags: abi

Seems important if I wish / need to change the signature of my action later that I could add new optional parameters to avoid breaking changes within possible.

Is it possible to update the ABI to add a new optional parameter? If so, how?

Alternatively or additionally, can I receive a `map<string, string>` as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type?` for optionals, similar to `type[]` for arrays.

Comment: Is there an example of that?